# Managing php sessions on multiple file uploads

Tags: php, session, file-upload

I'm working in a multiple image upload social web app. I'm assigning a `$_session['file_id']` to each uploaded file as an array index (file id comes from db). But I only want users to upload a maximum of 4 images per post. So I'm counting the `images.length` before upload, and if it's `== 4`, alerting the user he can't upload more files at the same time, else, the normal upload happens. For security purposes I have an `unset($_session['file_id'])` for making sure the 4 files won't be uploaded on errors, or user changes on javascript (a `for` loop on every upload, to count `$_session['file_id'])`.
 The problem I'm having is that the js itself ain't enought to make sure the file ain't uploaded 4 times, I guess ajax upload stay on queue, and check for file number before the 4th file is uploaded. Is there any other approach I can use direct on php, remembering I can't unset files for common users (4 files are already upload and waiting for send button), but I need plus to unset files if user reflesh, or quit the page? Thank your for your time.

**JavaScript**

```
var checkfilecount = 0;
$('#file').change(function() {
    checkfilecount++;
    checkfile = $("#images).length;
    if (checkfile < 4 && checkfilecount < 4) {
        $("#filesend").submit();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("Sorry, You can`t upload too many files at once")
        },3000)
    }
})
```

and on #postsend:

```
checkfilecount = 0;
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['files_id'])) {
    $counting = 0; 
    foreach($_SESSION['files_id'] as $key => $val)
    {
        $counting++;
        if ($counting == 4) {
            unset($_SESSION['files_id']);       
            exit("error on session array"); 
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Edit your post and add code.

Comment: Line 4: `checkfile =      $("#images).length;` misses a `"` at the end of `$('#images)`, it needs to be `$("#images")`.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a random classname to the `<input>`s for example:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="fileuploadCounter">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="fileuploadCounter">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="fileuploadCounter">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="fileuploadCounter">
</form>
```

After init, `$('.fileuploadCounter').length()` will return the amount of elements with that class, in this example, four. See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

---

**Old answer underneath**

Change the name on the `<input>` tags to `images[]`, and count `$_POST['images']` server side.

Eg:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
</form>

<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

            // Because we added [] in the name tag and they match names, $_FILES['file'] is now an array containing the images. 

            if(count($_FILES['file']) > 4){

                // More than 4 files

            }
            else
            {

                // Less then four!

                foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file){
                    move_uploaded_file($file["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $files["file"]["name"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Thew, but that was not the problem. What i need is a client side way to count the imgs, and only send to php if they are less than 4, i tryied 2 ways in my code, but none works. And plus i would need an approach to check if the user quit the page and has restart the upload (if i wont unset the session array than the user will receive the limit message even when reflesh the page, but if i unset without a frontend check, the user will lost his uploaded files) Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Javascript counting images is unsafe if you check without the PHP side. Any user could edit your code and send a thousand images if they wanted.

Comment: I knew, my approach is unsetting if it reaches the 5 file on php side, but only if the user pass the js limit (if the user modify js).

Comment: In my code i have only one file input, but i using the same approach, but with the uploaded images class, and a filecount var. The problem is that the submit sometimes happens before the filecount, or file.length happens. probably cause of ajax async.

Comment: EDIT: I put the count++ after submit every image (i was using it before the submit, thinking of async, but wont work) and it worked, guess it will have some issues yet, but i get it. Thank you @Thew.